# What value of Y have a Bernoulli (1/2) distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bernoulli-numbers

Let $X$ be a random variable with p.d.f. $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\beta}e^{-x/\beta}  1_{[0,∞)}(x)$$

, where $\beta > 0$.

For a positive number $b$, let us define a random variable $Y$ as

$$Y =\begin{cases} 1 &,\text{ if } X > b \\  0 &,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$

For what value of $b$ will $Y$ have a Bernoulli$(1/2)$ distribution?

Comment: Please show your work. What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm other words, what is the median of $X$? Why, it's $\beta\ln 2$, of course.